# Find the Error or memory leak

Tags: c++11, linked-list

I was writing LinkedList Program in C++
Here is the Code. Find the Error and Memory Leak or anything else.
I want to write a perfect code.

```
#ifndef LEARN_REVERSELINKLIST_H
#define LEARN_REVERSELINKLIST_H

#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>

class ReverseLinkList {
private:
    struct Node {
        std::string string;
        Node *Previous{};
        Node *Next{};
    };

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;

    int count;

public:
    ReverseLinkList();
    ~ReverseLinkList();

    void insert(std::string string);
    void insertAt(std::string string, int position);
    void iterator() const;
    void reverseIterator() const;
    void remove(const std::string &string);
    void removeAt(int position);
    int size() const;
    Node *getHead() const;
    Node *getTail() const;
};

#endif //LEARN_REVERSELINKLIST_H
```

and Here is the CC File

```
#include "ReverseLinkList.h"

    ReverseLinkList::~ReverseLinkList() {
    if (count != 0) {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp != tail->Next) {
            delete temp->Previous;
            temp = temp->Next;
        }
        tail = nullptr;
        head = nullptr;
    }
}

ReverseLinkList::ReverseLinkList()
        : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), count(0) {
}

void ReverseLinkList::iterator() const {
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(count != 0, "List is empty");
    Node *temp;
    temp = head;

    while (temp != tail->Next) {
        std::cout << temp->string << std::endl;
        temp = temp->Next;
    }
}

void ReverseLinkList::reverseIterator() const {
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(count != 0, "List is empty");
    Node *temp;
    temp = tail;
    while (temp != head->Previous) {
        std::cout << temp->string << std::endl;
        temp = temp->Previous;
    }
}

void ReverseLinkList::insert(std::string string) {
    auto *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->string = std::move(string);
    count++;
    if (head == nullptr && tail == nullptr) {
        newNode->Previous = nullptr;
        newNode->Next = nullptr;
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        tail->Next = newNode;
        newNode->Next = nullptr;
        newNode->Previous = tail;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}

int ReverseLinkList::size() const {
    return count;
}

void ReverseLinkList::remove(const std::string &string) {
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(count != 0, "List is empty");
    if (count == 1) {
        if (head->string == string) {
            delete head;
            head = nullptr;
            tail = nullptr;
        }
        count--;
        return;
    }

    if (head->string == string) {
        Node *temp;
        temp = head->Next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
        head->Previous = nullptr;
        count--;
        return;
    }
    if (tail->string == string) {
        Node *temp;
        temp = tail->Previous;
        delete tail;
        tail = temp;
        temp->Next = nullptr;
        count--;
        return;
    }
    Node *temp;
    temp = head;
    bool verbose = true;
    while (temp != tail->Next) {
        if (temp->string == string) {
            verbose = false;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->Next;
    }

    if (verbose) {
        std::cerr << "Node not present" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    Node *previous, *next;
    previous = temp->Previous;
    next = temp->Next;

    delete temp;
    previous->Next = next;
    next->Previous = previous;
    count--;
}

void ReverseLinkList::insertAt(std::string string, int position) {
    if (position > count)
        return;

    if (position == 0) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            insert(string);
            return;
        }
        auto *newNode = new Node;
        newNode->string = string;
        newNode->Previous = nullptr;
        head->Previous = newNode;
        newNode->Next = head;
        head = newNode;
        count++;
        return;
    }

    if (position == count - 1) {
        insert(string);
        return;
    }

    Node *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (position != 0) {
        temp = temp->Next;
        position--;
    }

    Node *next;
    next = temp->Next;

    auto *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->string = string;

    temp->Next = newNode;
    newNode->Previous = temp;
    newNode->Next = next;
    next->Previous = newNode;

    count++;
}

ReverseLinkList::Node *ReverseLinkList::getHead() const {
    return head;
}

ReverseLinkList::Node *ReverseLinkList::getTail() const {
    return tail;
}

void ReverseLinkList::removeAt(int position) {
    BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(count != 0, "List is empty");
    if (position > count)
        return;
    Node *temp;
    if (count == 1) {
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        count--;
        return;
    }

    if (position == 0) {
        temp = head->Next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
        head->Previous = nullptr;
        count--;
        return;
    }
    if (position == count) {
        temp = tail->Previous;
        delete tail;
        tail = temp;
        tail->Next = nullptr;
        count--;
        return;
    }
    temp = head;
    while (position != 0) {
        temp = temp->Next;
        position--;
    }
    Node *previous;
    Node *next;

    previous = temp->Previous;
    next = temp->Next;
    delete temp;
    previous->Next = next;
    next->Previous = previous;
    count--;
}
```

I would like to have some suggestion how can I write better code and Implement it. If you have some functions you would like to add please do post.
My next move is to make this code using templates

Comment: most of your functions don't really deal well with the case of an empty list, this includes the destructor.

Comment: Ok, I have added a condition of
        assert (count != 0);

Comment: Requesting you to move this question to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @CinCout I believe Code Review is only for _working_ programs (where the author is looking for _better ways of making it work_) and I don't believe they'd appreciate "find my memory leak" type posts.

Comment: @TripeHound The OP wants to *"write a perfect code."* Meaning to say he has a piece of working code, and wants to optimize it for time and space complexities. I'd any day choose CR over SO for such questions.

Comment: @CinCout The title implies there's a memory leak (and a comment implies it's potentially buggy for empty lists). If either is the case, the OP shouldn't move. If OP is pretty certain the code _does_ work, and _is_ just looking for suggestions for improvements, then it may be OK (but using a different title).

Comment: Sorry guys, I just started using SO. If my title is bugging you, from my next post I will try to do better. @CinCout I will look into CR also. the above code is working, but i want to optimize at certain level so that it could be a presentable one.

Comment: @NesplNS3 The reason I mentioned the title (and challenged CinCout about moving the question to code review) is that code review **is** the place for seeking to improve/optimise code, **but**, while I don't frequent it as much as here, I believe they insist any code posted should tested and working (as far as reasonable). If you're reasonably sure the code *is* working, then code-review is the right place. But if the title (or any introductory text) gives the impression that it might be buggy, they're likely to close, so just be careful how you title/describe it.

Comment: We on CR need the code to be working as expected. The title should describe what the code is doing. Hence if the code is working as intended you are welcome to come to Code Review where we try to make your code shine. Just keep in mind that doing a code review will take some time so don't expect to get answers as fast as on [SO].

Comment: `delete temp; temp = temp->Next;` You have undefined behavior right there - you dereference a pointer that you've just deallocated one line above.

Comment: `remove()` would break when removing the only node in a one-node list. `temp` would be null, and then `head = temp; head->Previous = nullptr;` would dereference  a null pointer.

Comment: `insertAt` doesn't allow inserting in front of the list, before `head`. One might naively think that `insertAt("whatever", 0)` would do that, but instead this call would crash.

Comment: `removeAt(0)` has the same problem as `remove()` when removing the only node from a one-node list. Also, `if(position == count)` seems to be off-by-one. There are `count` nodes - you could choose to number them `0` through `count-1` or `1` through `count`, but in no case would `0` and `count` both be valid positions.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `removeAt ()` `remove ()` `insert ()` and `insertAt ()` has been modified. thanks you. my approach is little bit noob but please bear with me. I am learning

Comment: Looks like the OP needs to decide if his code is working or not :P
But as he said in one of the comments above, *"the above code is working, but i want to optimize at certain level so that it could be a presentable one"*.  This makes it a perfect candidate for CR. Just make sure to change the title though!

Comment: @CinCout I should join English classes also :0 . until Mr. IgorTandetnik pointed those error, I was thinking my code was working but that was my fault. _OK. the above code is working was little bit over confident_

Comment: `~ReverseLinkList` destructor now leaks one node.

Comment: `insertAt("something", count)` dereferences null pointer. You probably meant to use `if (position == count)` there.